# Predefined math functions like arg min/max

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics

Is there a list of math functions that include functions like arg min/max? This is coming from a programmer, so it'd be cool to see the math "package" of math.

Edit: I mean this in the context of math, not a programming language.

Comment: You want an exhaustive list? I doubt such a thing exists.

Comment: I mean a reasonably complete list...how else would people know what the notation means?

Comment: It depends on the language, available libraries, etc. Probably have better luck asking on SO.

Comment: I mean this in the context of math though, not programming.

Comment: Try this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_functions. Besides, any good textbook will explain what the function does.

Comment: I found a pretty good link from the link you gave me: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations

Comment: There's also an ISO standard although it seems more focused on symbols rather than functions. I don't think it's very popular in the math community. https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:80000:-2:ed-2:v1:en